# Update query taking forever

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, plpgsql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table `my_obj` with two fields `value_a varchar(5)` and `value_b varchar(5)`

Indeed the two values don't vary so much, and can be grouped in a pair. At best that gives a maximum number < 100 pairs. On the contrary I have several millions records in `my_obj`.

All the queries interfering with `value_a` and `value_b` take a really long time. So I have decided to create the table pair for all possible pairs, with the fields `value_a` and `value_b`. And consequently I have added a field id_pair in the table `my_obj`.

I have already filled the table pair with all its pairs, it is ok.
So, now, I wanted to update the table `my_obj` accordingly with this command:

```
update my_obj
set id_pair = p.id
from my_obj as o
inner join pair as p on p.value_a = o.value_a and p.value_b = o.value_b;
```

While the query was launched for a long time, I have run a `select count(*) from my_obj where id_pair > 0;` and it returned me `0`

So there was a problem in my update query.
**EDIT / N.B.**: plpgsql functions, which are a transaction units, perform the commit at the end of the transaction, so *it was completely normal* that I saw no modification in the table since I interupted the function.

I changed the update query with a criteria on the primary key of `my_obj`, so as to perform only one `update` on only one record.

```
update my_obj
set id_pair = p.id
from my_obj as o
inner join pair as p on p.value_a = o.value_a and p.value_b = o.value_b
where o.id = 1234567;  -- 1234567 being the key of an existing record
```

Astonishingly, when I launched this query that should `update` only one record, it seems to take **forever**.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is there an index on my_obj.id?

Comment: Did you by any chance try to run the second update while the first one was still running?

Comment: @Gerrat in postgresql primary key have automatically an index, so yes.

Comment: @AndriyM No I interrupted the first one so as to do the second check test.

Comment: Do you have indexes on `value_a` and `value_b` columns on the involved tables?

Comment: @Diego I have an index on value_a and value_b on the pair table, not on the my_obj table.

Comment: I suppose what you're doing is actually creating a manual index on these values in the my_obj table.  It would probably be easier to create an explicit index on both of them.

Comment: you mean create a foreign key, with a default value, and then update that foreign key to its real value... ok... but does that explain that the single update query takes soo long ? I mean the `where o.id = 123456` **should** be fast.

Comment: The subquery is *uncorrelated*. The table `my_obj` is present two times (once as the target, once in the subquery) in the rangetable, only one of the entries is anchored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How does this work for you?

```
update my_obj o
set    id_pair = p.id
from   pair p
where  p.value_a = o.value_a and
       p.value_b = o.value_b and
       o.id = 1234567;
```

Comment: @StephaneRolland Please accept the answer when SO will let you.